# Covering legacy C style functions using C++ template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following two functions in C.

```
float floatAdd(float a, float b)
{
    return a+b;
}

double doubleAdd(double a, double b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Now, I would like to combine both functions and write a tempalte function in C++ as follows.

```
template<class T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    // if T=float, return floatAdd(a,b)
    // if T=double, return doubleAdd(a,b)

}
```

Since the return types are different, I am unable to find a solution!

Please note that the above functions are very simple, and used as merely an example. My intention is provide a C++ template wrapper for some Legacy C functions the kind explained the example.

Comment: And your question is .... what?

Comment: Why not return `a + b`?

Comment: @tkausl: This is merely an example. I need to call some legacy C functions.

Comment: If you need to call different functions depending on the type of parameters you (most likely) need to use overloads, not templates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example doesn't really show the need to use the specific functions. But in a more general case, you can provide a specific implementation for a template function or template class for a given set of template arguments. The feature is known as [Template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) and is specifically designed to address this problem.

```
template<class T>
T add(T a, T b);

// Special implementation for floatAdd
template<>
float add<float>(float a, float b)
{
    return floatAdd(a, b);
}

// Special implementation for floatDouble
template<>
double add<double>(double a, double b)
{
    return doubleAdd(a, b);
}
```

For such a simple case, you can simply use a regular template :

```
template<class T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

If you don't care about supporting a general case, you can just use function overloading and forget about templates :

```
float add(float a, float b)
{
    return floatAdd(a, b);
}

double add(double a, double b)
{
    return doubleAdd(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Is it supported in C++ 11?

Comment: I'm not sure when template specialization came to be, but it's not a recent feature. C++11 definitively supports this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: templates and template specialization have been around since the 1990s.