# Template function to cover legacy C functions with different return types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I need to write a template function in C++ to cover some legacy C functions.

I will try to explain the situation using the following sample codes.

```
struct MyStruct_float
{
    float x;
    float y;
};


struct MyStruct_double
{
    double x;
    double y;
};


MyStruct_float myCFunction_float(float a, float b)
{
    MyStruct_float t;
    t.x = a;
    t.y = b;
    return t;
}

MyStruct_double myCFunction_double(double a, double b)
{
    MyStruct_double t;
    t.x = a;
    t.y = b;
    return t;
}


template<class T>
T1 myCPPFunction(T a, T b)
{
    // if T=float, return myCFunction_float(a,b). In this case, T1=MyStruct_float
    // if T=double, return myCFunction_double(a,b). In this case, T1=MyStruct_double
}
```

Please note that the return type of the C functions are also different. Also note that I don't have any control over the C functions or the structures defined.

How to implement the function myCPPFunction correctly using templates in C++11?

I have already asked a similar question and got answer at [Covering legacy C style functions using C++ template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539802/covering-legacy-c-style-functions-using-c-template)

But the return type is no longer a fundamental type in this question and the solution suggested there is working in this situation!

Comment: In this case, function overloading should be simpler.

Comment: @cpplearner: Function overloading will not work as we need to call internally different C functions which returns different structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just overload:

```
MyStruct_float myCPPFunction(float a, float b) { return myCFunction_float(a, b); }
MyStruct_double myCPPFunction(double a, double b) { return myCFunction_double(a, b); }
```

---

Or make an overloading object that does this for you. This is more complex in C++11 than it is in C++17, but it's still very doable:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct overloader : overloader<T>::type, overloader<Ts...>::type
{
    using type = overloader;
    using overloader<T>::type::operator();
    using overloader<Ts...>::type::operator();

    template <typename U, typename... Us>
    explicit overloader(U&& u, Us&&... us)
        : overloader<T>::type(std::forward<U>(u))
        , overloader<Ts...>::type(std::forward<Us>(us)...)
    { }
};

template <typename T>
struct overloader<T> {
    using type = T;
};

template <class R, class... Args>
class overloader<R(*)(Args...)>
{
public:
    using type = overloader;

    explicit overloader(R (*p)(Args...))
        : ptr_(p)
    { }

    R operator()(Args... args) const
    {
        return ptr_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    R (*ptr_)(Args...);
};


template <typename... Ts>
overloader<typename std::decay<Ts>::type...>
overload(Ts&&... ts) {
    return overloader<typename std::decay<Ts>::type...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

With that:

```
auto myCPPFunction = overload(MyCFunction_float, MyCFunction_double);
```